# Angular add different style to a JSON

Tags: json, angular, parsing, format, styles

From BE it returns a json and I show it, but I would like, for example, `"type, includeDeactive, code etc..."` be  bold and the (other) value, after the colons (:) in italics.
Example:

```
body:   {   "**type**: {    **includeDeactive**: *false*,    **code**: *null*,    **address**: *null*,    **name**: *null*,    }
```

I've already formatted the json with the `<pre>` tag and I pass it data with the data binding `{{detail.body | json }}`. This is my html:

```html
<mat-label style="font-family: Roboto">
    <strong>Body</strong>:
    <span style="font-family: Roboto"> 
    <pre id="formatJson"> {{detail.body | json }} </pre>
    </span>
</mat-label>
```

This is my function in ts:

```
  objBody: any;
  parsedObj: any;

   constructor(
      private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DettaglioAuditComponent>,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
      private auditService: AuditService,
    ) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.detail = {};
      this.auditService.getDetails(this.data.element).then(
        (value) => {
          this.detail = value;
          var objBody = JSON.stringify(this.detail.body);
          var parsedObj = JSON.parse(objBody);
            
          //objBody = objBody.replace('{"', '{"<b>'); - already tried but doesn't work!
          //objBody = objBody.replace('":', '</b>":');
          this.loading = false;
        },
        (error) => 
        });
    }
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, the best I can guess is : `JSON.parse` the content, recursively iterate on the keys of the given object and generate HTML out of it. If it is a matter of readability, you can maybe let [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) do the job instead.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I don't know highlightjs . Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it for professional purpose and "just want it to work", use [Highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) or an equivalent library. The output will be fancy and very readable :

[image]

**If you want to do it with Highlightjs**

You need highlightJs of course. You can use the npm dependency `ngx-highlight-js` which will enable you to use HighlightJs in an Angular project.

In the Angular project, you can include the content like this :

```html
<textarea highlight-js ngNonBindable lang="javascript">
 // include your content here
</textarea>
```

- You MUST include the content in a `<textarea>` tag (for indentation preservation)
- `highlight-js` is of course the directive that will tell HighlightJs to do its work
- `ngNonBindable` prevents Angular from trying to interpret the content of the textArea as Angular code
- `lang="javascript"` : you can optionally specify the language for accurate coloration
- Also, don't forget to import the `HighlightJsModule` module where necessary

**If you want to do it by yourself**

*(or understand how things work under the hood)*

You can `JSON.parse()` the content of your string, recursively iterate on the given object keys and generate HTML out of it.

- Indentations and newlines can be rendered by placing the generated html in a `<pre>` pr `<textarea>` tag
- Colors can be achieved by placing colored elements in dedicated `<span class="[...]">` tags

On the previous example, the HTML code generated by HighlightJS is :

```json
<pre><code class="language-json hljs">[
  {
    <span class="hljs-attr">"title"</span>: <span class="hljs-string">"apples"</span>,
    <span class="hljs-attr">"count"</span>: [<span class="hljs-number">12000</span>, <span class="hljs-number">20000</span>],
    <span class="hljs-attr">"description"</span>: {<span class="hljs-attr">"text"</span>: <span class="hljs-string">"..."</span>, <span class="hljs-attr">"sensitive"</span>: <span class="hljs-literal">false</span>}
  },
  {
    <span class="hljs-attr">"title"</span>: <span class="hljs-string">"oranges"</span>,
    <span class="hljs-attr">"count"</span>: [<span class="hljs-number">17500</span>, <span class="hljs-literal">null</span>],
    <span class="hljs-attr">"description"</span>: {<span class="hljs-attr">"text"</span>: <span class="hljs-string">"..."</span>, <span class="hljs-attr">"sensitive"</span>: <span class="hljs-literal">false</span>}
  }
]
</code></pre>
```

Relevant pieces of code :

- Convert the content to an object with `JSON.parse(contentAsString)`
- Check if a given property is an array with `Array.isArray(obj)`
- Iterate on object keys with `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: thank you! I will try but the problem is I don't know the data that the backend passes  to me.  Data changes every time (once an array, another a string or an object etc. ..), so I was looking for a way to manage the style, for example before and after the colon. Anyway thanks, very helpful and kind! I'll try it!

Comment: If you are using HighlightJS, you  don't need to care, just drop the content in the textArea. If you do it manually, you will have to manually check if it is an array, an object or a litteral.